# How do I get a list of column names from a psycopg2 cursor?

Tags: python, psycopg2

I would like a general way to generate column labels directly from the selected column names, and recall seeing that python's psycopg2 module supports this feature.

Answer (score 364):

From "Programming Python" by Mark Lutz:

```
curs.execute("Select * FROM people LIMIT 0")
colnames = [desc[0] for desc in curs.description]
```

Comment: If you just want the column names, don't select all of the rows in the table. This is more efficient: `curs.execute("SELECT * FROM people LIMIT 0")`

Comment: It may be worth adding that this works for views as well as tables, whereas it’s not (easily) possible to get column names for views from `information_schema`.

Comment: Might be more intuitive to get the name as an attribute:

colnames = [desc.name for desc in curs.description]

Comment: Important to note that column names read from the cursor description function come out in lowercase.
```curs.execute("Select userId FROM people")
colnames = [desc[0] for desc in curs.description]
assert colnames == ['userid']```

Comment: `curs.description` for me is None, and I'm not sure why... I'm querying against Redshift, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Or in one line : pd.read_sql("Select * FROM <table_name> LIMIT 1", con=engine).columns

Answer (score 95):

Another thing you can do is to create a cursor with which you will be able to reference your columns by their names (that's a need which led me to this page in the first place):

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor

ps_conn = psycopg2.connect(...)
ps_cursor = psql_conn.cursor(cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)

ps_cursor.execute('select 1 as col_a, 2 as col_b')
my_record = ps_cursor.fetchone()
print (my_record['col_a'],my_record['col_b'])

>> 1, 2
```

Comment: please reference the source of the info

Comment: In my case the "as col_a" was unnecessary. I omitted it and the records returned by the cursor used the column names from my table.

Answer (score 35):

To **get the column names in a separate query**, you can query the information_schema.columns table.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import psycopg2

if __name__ == '__main__':
  DSN = 'host=YOUR_DATABASE_HOST port=YOUR_DATABASE_PORT dbname=YOUR_DATABASE_NAME user=YOUR_DATABASE_USER'

  column_names = []

  with psycopg2.connect(DSN) as connection:
      with connection.cursor() as cursor:
          cursor.execute("select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_schema = 'YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME' and table_name='YOUR_TABLE_NAME'")
          column_names = [row[0] for row in cursor]

  print("Column names: {}\n".format(column_names))
```

To **get column names in the same query as data rows**, you can use the description field of the cursor:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import psycopg2

if __name__ == '__main__':
  DSN = 'host=YOUR_DATABASE_HOST port=YOUR_DATABASE_PORT dbname=YOUR_DATABASE_NAME user=YOUR_DATABASE_USER'

  column_names = []
  data_rows = []

  with psycopg2.connect(DSN) as connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
      cursor.execute("select field1, field2, fieldn from table1")
      column_names = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
      for row in cursor:
        data_rows.append(row)

  print("Column names: {}\n".format(column_names))
```

Answer (score 28):

If you want to have a named tuple obj from db query you can use the following snippet:

```
from collections import namedtuple

def create_record(obj, fields):
    ''' given obj from db returns named tuple with fields mapped to values '''
    Record = namedtuple("Record", fields)
    mappings = dict(zip(fields, obj))
    return Record(**mappings)

cur.execute("Select * FROM people")
colnames = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]
rows = cur.fetchall()
cur.close()
result = []
for row in rows:
    result.append(create_record(row, colnames))
```

This allows you to access record values as if they were class properties i.e.

> record.id,  record.other_table_column_name,   etc.

or even shorter

```
from psycopg2.extras import NamedTupleCursor
with cursor(cursor_factory=NamedTupleCursor) as cur:
   cur.execute("Select * ...")
   return cur.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 26):

If you're looking to get a pandas data frame *with column headers already associated*, try this:

```
import psycopg2, pandas

con=psycopg2.connect(
    dbname=DBNAME, 
    host=HOST, 
    port=PORT, 
    user=USER, 
    password=PASSWORD
)

sql = """
select * from x
"""

d = pandas.read_sql_query(sql,con)

con.close()

print(type(d))

print(pandas.DataFrame.head(d))
```

Comment: This seems to me the easiest. I'm surprised you would have to do a separate query to get column names. Worked for me.

Comment: Totally agreed, @ChuckPedro

Comment: easiest method. this should have more upvotes

Comment: This is the easiest by far, but is quite slow. The fastest way to do this is using `pd.DataFrame(np.array(cur.fetchall()))`, which comes with a sequence of numbers as column names.

Answer (score 8):

After executing SQL query write following python script written in 2.7

```
total_fields = len(cursor.description)    
fields_names = [i[0] for i in cursor.description   
    Print fields_names
```

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed that you must use [`cursor.fetchone()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html) after the query to get the list of columns in [`cursor.description`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-description.html) (i.e in `[desc[0] for desc in curs.description]`)

Answer (score 1):

```
 # You can use this function
 def getColumns(cursorDescription):
     columnList = []
     for tupla in cursorDescription:
         columnList.append(tupla[0])
     return columnList
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to turn all your data in a Pandas Dataframe with column names:

```
cur.execute("select * from tablename")
datapoints = cur.fetchall()
cols = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]
df = pd.DataFrame((datapoints) , columns=[cols])
```

Comment: ```df = pd.DataFrame(datapoints, columns=cols)```

`cols` is already a list, so adding square brackets is creating a multi-index

Answer (score 0):

I also used to face similar issue. I use a simple trick to solve this.
Suppose you have column names in a list like

```
col_name = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Then you can do following

```
for row in cursor.fetchone():
    print zip(col_name, row)
```

Answer (score -7):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import psycopg2
#note that we have to import the Psycopg2 extras library!
import psycopg2.extras
import sys

def main():
    conn_string = "host='localhost' dbname='my_database' user='postgres' password='secret'"
    # print the connection string we will use to connect
    print "Connecting to database\n ->%s" % (conn_string)

    # get a connection, if a connect cannot be made an exception will be raised here
    conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)

    # conn.cursor will return a cursor object, you can use this query to perform queries
    # note that in this example we pass a cursor_factory argument that will
    # dictionary cursor so COLUMNS will be returned as a dictionary so we
    # can access columns by their name instead of index.
    cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)

    # tell postgres to use more work memory
    work_mem = 2048

    # by passing a tuple as the 2nd argument to the execution function our
    # %s string variable will get replaced with the order of variables in
    # the list. In this case there is only 1 variable.
    # Note that in python you specify a tuple with one item in it by placing
    # a comma after the first variable and surrounding it in parentheses.
    cursor.execute('SET work_mem TO %s', (work_mem,))

    # Then we get the work memory we just set -> we know we only want the
    # first ROW so we call fetchone.
    # then we use bracket access to get the FIRST value.
    # Note that even though we've returned the columns by name we can still
    # access columns by numeric index as well - which is really nice.
    cursor.execute('SHOW work_mem')

    # Call fetchone - which will fetch the first row returned from the
    # database.
    memory = cursor.fetchone()

    # access the column by numeric index:
    # even though we enabled columns by name I'm showing you this to
    # show that you can still access columns by index and iterate over them.
    print "Value: ", memory[0]

    # print the entire row 
    print "Row: ", memory

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```