# How to describe columns (get their names, data types, etc.) of a SQL query in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, cursor

I need a way to get a "description" of the columns from a SELECT query (cursor), such as their names, data types, precision, scale, etc., in PostgreSQL (or better yet PL/pgSQL).

I'm transitioning from Oracle PL/SQL, where I can get such description using a built-in procedure dbms_sql.describe_columns. It returns an array of records, one for each column of a given (parsed) cursor.

EDB has it implemented too (https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/en/9.0/oracompat/Postgres_Plus_Advanced_Server_Oracle_Compatibility_Guide-127.htm#P13324_681237)

An examples of such query:

```
select col1 from tab where col2 = :a
```

I need an API (or a workaround) that could be called like this (hopefully):

```
select query_column_description('select col1 from tab where col2 = :a');
```

that will return something similar to:

```
{{"col1","numeric"}}
```

Why? We build views where these queries become individual columns. For example, view's query would look like the following:

```
select (select col1 from tab where col2 = t.colA) as col1::numeric
  from tab_main t
```

Comment: Something similar is available using psycopg2 (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252247/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-column-names-from-a-psycopg2-cursor), but I was hoping I could stay within PL/pgSQL, so I don't have to deal with (install/learn/etc.) psycopg2 just for this (and maybe some other cool/needed features I've yet to discover)

Comment: There is nothing built-in on the server side. On the client side I know that JDBC can do that, and I guess ODBC as well. I assume both interfaces use [SPI](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/spi-interface-support.html) for this.

Comment: Please upvote the answer if it is ok for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/21c7a/2

You can use systems table :

First step create a temporary view with your query (without clause where)

```
create or replace view temporary view a_view as
    select col1 from tab
```

then select

```
select
    row_to_json(t.*)
from (
    select 
        column_name,
        data_type
    from
        information_schema.columns
    where
        table_schema = 'public' and
        table_name   = 'a_view'
) as t
```

Comment: Thank you @Indent. I'll use your workaround by creating a temp view.

Comment: ok, cool. Please upvote the answer if it is ok for you. Thanks. Have a good day.

Comment: Sorry @Indent, I can't upvote because of my low reputation. Your answer however helped me a lot. Thanks again.